# In Java : How to duplicate "entirely" a Map with Collections as value?

Tags: java, shallow-copy, cloning

The code below is illustrating my problem :

```
public class TreeMapCopyProblem {

    private static TreeMap<Integer, SortedSet<Integer>> treeMap1;

    private static TreeMap<Integer, SortedSet<Integer>> treeMap2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        fillTreeMap1();
        initializeTreeMap2();
        test();
    }

    private static void initializeTreeMap2() {
        treeMap2 = (TreeMap<Integer, SortedSet<Integer>>) treeMap1.clone();
    }

    private static void fillTreeMap1() {
        treeMap1 = new TreeMap<>();
        SortedSet<Integer> values0 = Stream.of(0).collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
        SortedSet<Integer> values1 = Stream.of(1).collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
        SortedSet<Integer> values2 = Stream.of(2).collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));

        treeMap1.put(0, values0);
        treeMap1.put(1, values1);
        treeMap1.put(2, values2);

        //Once fill, this treeMap does not have to be modified anymore
    }

    private static void test(){
        treeMap2.get(0).add(99);
        System.out.println(treeMap1);
    }

}
```

TreeMap1 is modified too because it's a shallow Copy referring to the same set.

I had the same behaviour using

`treeMap2 = new TreeMap<>(treeMap1);`
or
`treeMap2.putAll(treeMap1);`

So... How do we simply do a non shallow copy of an existing Tree Map so we can initialize a new TreeMap from an existing one and then modify only the second one?

Answer (score 1):

> How do we simply do a non shallow copy of an existing Tree Map so we can initialize a new TreeMap from an existing one and then modify only the second one?

Supposing that you don't feel the need to make copies of the `Integer` objects involved (which are, after all, immutable), we only need to go one level deeper to make a sufficiently deep copy of your original map.  I would probably do that by streaming and then collecting the original map's entry set:

```
private static void initializeTreeMap2() {
    treeMap2 = treeMap1.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(TreeMap::new,
            (m, e) -> m.put(e.getKey(), new TreeSet<>(e.getValue())),
            (m1, m2) -> m1.putAll(m2));
}
```

This is similar in concept to your `forEach()`-based approach, but it feels a bit cleaner to me.  Among other things, there is no way for any thread to observe a partially filled state of `treeMap2`.  Also, this stream-based approach is auto-parallelizable, whereas `forEach()` is unavoidably serial.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am glad to speak with an other developper.
By the way I am doubtful with `TreeMap::putAll`

`treeMap2.putAll(treeMap1)` also gives a shallow copy. Why is it different here ?

I wanted to try your code but intelliJ says "void is not a functional interface"

Also, your code is kind of code I don't understand at all. I am still lacking experience...
What are (m, e, m1, m2) ?

Comment: @EtienneSavary, the needed deep copies are made via the lambda given by the second argument.  The `putAll` is used, if and when necessary, to combine new maps containing those copies.  Do study the docs of [`Stream.collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) if you're uncertain about how it works.

Comment: And `m`, `e`, `m1`, `m2` are parameters of lambdas, just as are the `integer` and `integers` in your own solution.

Comment: I am sorry, I really can't try your code : 

java: no suitable method found for collect(TreeMap::new,(m,e)->m.p[...]e())),(m1,m2)->T[...]utAll)
    method java.util.stream.Stream.<R>collect(java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,? super java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.Integer,java.util.SortedSet<java.lang.Integer>>>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R
        (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
          missing return value))

Comment: method java.util.stream.Stream.<R,A>collect(java.util.stream.Collector<? super java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.Integer,java.util.SortedSet<java.lang.Integer>>,A,R>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,A
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))

I am using Java 17

Comment: @EtienneSavary, the three-argument variation of `Stream.collect()` has been available [since Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-), and it is still present in Java 21.  That is what the code in this answer is using, and it compiles just fine for me (but do note the minor correction I made earlier).  If your Java compiler is rejecting it then either there's something else wrong in your code or your Java environment is broken.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static void initializeTreeMap2() {
    treeMap2 = (new TreeMap<>());
    treeMap1.forEach((integer, integers) -> {
        SortedSet<Integer> newSet = new TreeSet<>(integers);
        treeMap2.put(integer, newSet);
    });
}
```

This works. But is it the good approach ?

(Note putAll method also give a shallow copy.)

Comment: Without any comments on the functionality, naming two adjacent variables `integer` and `integers` is a good way of making someone's day.

Comment: :D Happy to have made someone 's day. :)))
I must confess I let intelliJ name these variables. But we understand don't we ?

Are m e m1 m2 better ? :) (please, I seriously need explanation for this code from John 's answer)

By the way, key and sortedSetValues would have been best here, you're right. :)